# AWS S3 file has no contents when downloading

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

I am trying to pass a file from S3 directly into the users' download stream like this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Download()
{
    var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    var stream = new MemoryStream();

    using (var client = new AmazonS3Client(RegionEndpoint.USWest2))
    {
        var request = new GetObjectRequest
        {
            BucketName = "bucket",
            Key = "filename"
        };

        using (var response = client.GetObject(request))
        {
            response.ResponseStream.CopyTo(stream);
        }
    }

    result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(mimeType);

    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
    {
        FileName = "file.pdf"
    };

    return result;
}
```

But the file downloads as 0 bytes. I assumed that the file is completely loaded in memory on line `ResponseStream.CopyTo`.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `response` from within the using block? Also you may need to `Seek` to position 0 of the `ResponseStream` before you try to the `CopyTo`.

Comment: Ah yes that was the culprit, I had to rewind the stream before passing it on.